# How do I run a command on the file name under the cursor

Tags: vimscript

I like the functionality of `gf` but for certain files I would like to run some (non-Vim) code on the file prior to displaying it in my window.  Is there a way to capture the filename under the cursor so it can be used in a shortcut?

For example, I want to create a shortcut that would run `<custom_unix_script> <file>` (where  is under the cursor) and display those results in a new buffer or tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @Luc Hermitte's answer of using `expand(<cfile>)`, you can also use the `:!` command to run a shell command. You could do something like the following:

```
nnoremap gf :execute "!<custom_unix_script> " . expand(<cfile>)
```

- `nnoremap`: Creates a normal mode non-recursive mapping
- `:execute`: Allows us to build the command on the fly
- `:!...`: Runs the following command in your shell
- `expand(<cfile>)`: Uses the file-like word under your cursor

Note that this will do this for ALL files. If you want to filter by certain files you'll need to get a little bit more fancy. I'd recommend calling a function and doing a conditional on the output of `expand(<cfile>)`.

See `:h expand`, `:h <cword>`, `:h execute`, and `:h !cmd` for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The filename under the cursor can be obtained with `expand(<cfile>)`. From there you can do whatever you wish.

If you want more precisions, you'll need to provide us more precisions.